# Making clicked navbar element a different color

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

I'm using a navigation bar and I'm trying to make it so that when one of the elements of the navigation bar are clicked, they turn a different color. Right now, the default is this bland greyish color and I want it to be a shade of purple.
[This is what it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5GqJ.png)

HTML & CSS:

```css
.navbar {
 background-color: #57068c;
 font-family: "Kalinga";
}

.navbar-header a{
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;

}

.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-static-top a{
 color:white;
}

/*Formatting for main navbar elements*/
.navbar-collapse.collapse ul li a{
 color: white;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse ul li a:hover{
 color: #90dfff;
}

/*Formatting for all drop-down menus*/
.navbar-collapse.collapse ul li ul li a{
 color: white;
 background-color: #57068c;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse ul li ul li a:hover{
 background-color:#7b08c6;
}

/*Formatting for body and header tags*/
body{

 font-family: "Kalinga";
}

h1,h3 {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
 <head>
  <title>Site Header</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
  <meta name = "viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-sclae=1">
 </head>

 <body>
  
  <nav>
    <div class= "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
     <div class = "container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
       <!--Hamburger Menu Button and Logo-->
       <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = ".navbar-collapse">
        <span class ="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>

       <a class = "navbar-brand" href="#">SiteHeader</a>

      </div>


     <!--Nav igation Bar-->
      <div class = "navbar-collapse collapse">

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">

        <li class ="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">About<b class = "caret"></b></a>

         <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>


        <li class ="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">About<b class = "caret"></b></a>

         <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>


        <li class ="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">About<b class = "caret"></b></a>

         <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>

       </ul>
      </div>

     </div>

    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class = "container"> 

   <div class = "main">
    <div class = "page row" id = "starter">
     

     <div class = "col-sm-12">

      
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "page row" id = "Clubs AND Campus Map">
     <div class = "col-sm-6">
      
     </div>

     <div class = "col-sm-6">
      
     </div>

    </div>


    <div class = "page row" id = "Software AND Text and Teach">
     <div class = "col-sm-6">
      
     </div>

     <div class = "col-sm-6">
      
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>
  
   <footer>
    
   </footer>
  </div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Any help is super appreciated, this has me stumped.

Comment: You mean like a:visited? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #57068c;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/4/